# Need documentation for Soil Sensor from DIYmore

Tags: esp32, temperature-sensor

Does anyone have any documentation on this device?
Im just curious how it work out of the box and how to reference the on board temp and soil sensors.

Its a (for lack of a better name)a "ESP32 DHT11 WIFI Bluetooth Soil Temperature Humidity Sensor18650"
SKU:012592
[Item on DIYmore site](https://www.diymore.cc/products/esp32-wifi-bluetooth-cp2104-dht11-soil-temperature-humidity-sensor-18650-battery-base?_pos=13&_sid=c0fb7615d&_ss=r)

[image]

Comment: With a broken link to the manual on their website we're as clueless as you are.

Comment: @Majenko ...Right...I was just hoping someone somewhere once had one! I was hoping more data would come over the come post...but it not shedding much light.

Comment: You'll have to work out the schematic yourself by "buzzing out" the connections between the different components with a DMM.

Comment: The DHT11 is well documented with plenty of examples, if you can work out which pin of the ESP32 is used to communicate with it. The soil probe, likewise, looks like a simple pair of prongs with an op-amp for threshold detection - again well documented with lots of examples, if you can work out what pins it's on.

Comment: As Majenko said, without a manual or datasheet we cannot be sure (you can contact the seller about this), but it looks just like a ESP32 devboard, which already has some sensors on it. If it already "works" out of the box, I guess that means, that it comes with a working program flashed to it. Though you can also just write your own program in the Arduino framework. The sensors seem to be standard components. You would need to figure out, to which pins of the ESP32 they are connected. Thats again something, that the seller should be able to tell you.

Comment: @chrisl Well...though it "is" working...I cant see it (ble or wifi)..or communicate with it..Its actually comming to me via 3rd party...so it may have been flashed by others.

Comment: That looks like a copy of the [HiGrow sensor](https://hackaday.io/project/25253-higrow-plants-monitoring-sensor) from Hackaday.

Comment: @sempaiscuba Nice find. Chasing it down that rabbit hole leads, eventually, to TTGO as the originator: https://github.com/pesor/TTGO-T-HIGrow

Comment: @Majenko..that looks promising..

Comment: I am a bit old fashioned, as Ronald Reagan’s famous dictum, “Trust, but verify.” I always download it before ordering, there have been many suppliers that did not sell me stuff because the link was broken o data not available.

Comment: @Gil Good sound advice...It just happens that I got this device in a box with a bunch of other stuff...turns out I figured out all the thing and got a web server running with all the sensors.

Comment: Congratulations, a great job:-)